# Como pegar um input imagem e exibi-lo no background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um campo de input que deve receber uma imagem, ao recebe-la devo adiciona-la como `background-image` de uma div. Para isto, utilizei o FileReader para obter a base64 da imagem. Funciona bem, porém o CSS não consegue carregar a imagem. Como são inputs do usuário não consigo pegar uma URL.

Já tentei usando:

```
document.getElementById('div').style.backgoundImage = "url('${imageData}')";

.div{
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('${imageData}');
    }
```

Comment: Por que colocar no CSS se o JavaScript já alterou o background? Além do que o CSS é interpretado ao abrir a página, depois disso vc não consegue alterar o código-fonte dele.

Comment: O JavaScript não alterou o background, aqueles eram exemplos de tentativas falhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim você consegue fazer isso com a api [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Vale dar uma leitura também na seção de [suporte dos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#Browser_compatibility)

```js
function onSelectImage(event) {
 // se usuário não selecionou nenhum imagem não faça nada
 if (!event.target.files.length) return;

 // aqui pegaremos a primeira imagem da lista: FileList
 var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

 // FileReader https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
 var reader = new FileReader();

 // assim que terminar de ler a imagem
 // jogá-la como plano de fundo da div#image-area
 reader.onload = function(event) {
  document.querySelector('#image-area').style.background = "url('" + event.target.result + "') no-repeat 0 0";
 };

 // Informa ao reader para ler a image como base64
 reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}
```

```css
#image-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_input" onchange="onSelectImage(event)"/>
<div id="image-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Há dois erros no código:

1. Falta a letra **r** em `.backgoundImage`. Seria `.backgroundImage`.
2. A interpolação da string com *placeholder* `${}` só vai funcionar entre os sinais de crase:

```
    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageData})`;
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
let imageData = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg";
document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageData})`;
```

```html
<div id="div" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #000"></div>
```

Comment: Agradeço por ter corrigido os erros, escrevi muito rapidamente e não me atentei a isso. De qualquer forma no codigo que estou tentando usar está tudo certo.

Comment: Como disse na própria pergunta a imagem é um input, não terei a url dela.